# How to embed image inside HTML (not using LinkedResource or CDO)

Tags: c#, html

Here is situation:
I want to create HTML document with embeded image something like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img src="?" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Where "?" could somehow point to embeded image data. Maybe if javascript could decode base64 string generated by .net it could get me closer to my goal...
This document is generated on the fly and submited to document system. So I can not use any external link to the image using LinkedResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the MHTML format. It is used to combine HTML with embedded resources.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Make sure to take a look at the browsers supporting the format.

Comment: I figured out that MHTML is not the way to go because limited browser support, but it does partialy answer my question. However I found excelent alternative by generating fully compatibile pdf's using SharpPDF. This library just rocks! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some good link for generating mhtlm:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8268/Convert-any-URL-to-a-MHTML-archive-using-native-NE